# Why am I getting two different expressions for capacitance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

The question is:

A capacitor of capacitance C<sub>1</sub> is connected to a battery of potential V<sub>0</sub>. The battery is then disconnected and a second capacitor of capacitance C<sub>2</sub> is connected to the first capacitor. The new potential of the capacitors is V. Express C<sub>2</sub> in terms of C<sub>1</sub>, V<sub>0</sub> and V.

I made two approaches.

1. At first I used charge conservation. If q is the charge of the first capacitor, then after the second capacitor is connected, q will be distributed among them. If q<sub>1</sub> and q<sub>2</sub> are charges of capacitor 1 and 2, respectively, then $q = q_1 + q_2$. Using this,  I got $$C_2 = C_1*\frac{V_0-V}{V}$$
2. My second approach was using energy conservation. Before capacitor 2 was introduced, the energy saved in capacitor 1 was $E = \frac{1}{2}C_1V_0^2 $. Afterwards, the energy saved in each capacitor is given by, 
   $E_1 = \frac{1}{2}C_1V^2$ and $E_2 = \frac{1}{2}C_2V^2$. If I assume $E = E_1 + E_2$, I get $$C_2 = C_1*\frac{V_0^2-V^2}{V^2}$$

Why am I getting two different expressions? The energy I began with doesn't seem to be the energy I ended up with. Why is that?

Comment: You've discovered for yourself the 'two capacitor missing energy' paradox. There has been plenty of Q & A [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/437409/140996) and elsewhere online regarding the paradox.  Also, there is this Wikipedia article:  [Two capacitor paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_capacitor_paradox)